# How can I get a Spyder 2 colorimeter working?

Tags: 11.04, color-management

I've got a Spyder 2 colorimeter that I'm trying to get to work under Natty (11.04). I'm following the instructions that are outlined [here](http://jcornuz.wordpress.com/2007/11/18/use-colorvision-spyder-to-produce-an-icc-monitor-profile-under-argyllcms-linux/) and the output I'm getting in the terminal is:

```
Setting up the instrument
...aborted.
```

I've used this same device with success on Windows and on Ubuntu 10.04. I've tried using dispcalGUI which is a wrapper around the ArgyllCMS tools, and I get the same results.

How would I go about determining what is going wrong? I'm already running dispcal with the verbose flag and it's not being very verbose(!)

EDIT:

Here's some additional information about what I've tried so far and common solutions listed in the ArgyllCMS and dispcalGUI FAQ respectively.

1. Installed the driver using spyd2en and it works successfully.
2. Done *sudo chmod 777 /dev/bus/usb/002/006* to make the device read/write/executable by everybody. I understand the device entry changes, and I determined the correct entry using *lsusb*.
3. Run *dispcalGUI* as root.

This is the output of *lsusb*.

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 085c:0200 ColorVision, Inc. Monitor Spyder
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 045e:0039 Microsoft Corp. IntelliMouse Optical
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0402:9665 ALi Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as nobody has answered this, I thought I'd share my experiences as I've now managed to get the Spyder 2 colorimeter working.

The easiest solution? Upgrade to Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot.

The combination of the new kernel (3.0) and new version of ArgyllCMS (1.3.3 instead of 1.0.x) has made the Spyder 2 work again on my hardware. You can get fix this in 11.04 by using a 3.0 kernel and using the latest version of ArgyllCMS which you have to compile yourself, but *it's just so much easier to install Oneiric*.

I don't know what changed in the Linux kernel or ArgyllCMS, but I'm glad to report that this has now been fixed and my photos now look beautiful on my monitor :)